# How to create a method where multiple controls are false in an "if" statement for C#?

Tags: c#, if-statement, controls

What is the best way to simplify this (via method creation or otherwise):

```
if ((radioButton1.Checked == false) && (radioButton2.Checked == false) && (radioButton1.Checked == false) && ...more similar controls... && ((radioButton99.Checked == false))
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("Please select an option!);
}
```

Thank you for your consideration. Apologies for any inconvenience or grievances caused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put all those controls in a List and then check whether any of the controls in the list is checked. This can be done in several ways. Below examples of two of those.

Example using loop:

```
bool optionSelected = false;
foreach(var control in controls) // the List is in this case called controls
{
    if(control.Checked)
    {
        optionSelected = true;
    }
}
// Check the boolean
```

Example using System.Linq:

```
if(!controls.Any(c => c.Checked))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please select an option!);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm interested in your second solution but when creating

'List<> controls = new List<>();'

What should I put in the <>? "string"?

Comment: @Stoverflow whatever type the radiobutton is. So in this case I think that'd be RadioButton.

Comment: Update: I found it, it's a green word called RadioButton. Thanks again.

Comment: Apologies... but even when I had one of the radio buttons checked, the Message Box still appears... I like the second solution because it's short, even though it doesn't work now.

Comment: Are you sure the radiobutton is part of the list? The second example checks whether any radiobutton in the list is checked. Also, didn't you forget the "!" before it (it's very easy to forget)?

Comment: Apologies again! It's working now! My mistake is, I created a method to add the radio buttons to the List but I forgot to recall the method in my Form load. Now it's good, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your controls into a public collection to simply iterate them. 
if you have a bunch of the same type controls, it's better to put them into a array in your form's constructor :

```
 CheckBox[] MyBoxes = new CheckBox[]{ check01, check02 , ... }
 // MyBoxes is filled at Form_Load and it's usable in throughout of the form 
 bool result = true;
 for(int i=0; i<MyBoxes.Length; i++)
 { 
       if (MyBoxes[i].Checked == false)
        {  result = false; break; } 
 }
```

another solution is to iterate whole controls on the form:

```
 bool result = true;
 for(int i=0; i<this.Controls.Count; i++)
 { 
    if (this.Controls[i] is CheckBox)
    {
        if ((this.Controls[i] as CheckBox).Checked == false)
        {  result = false; break; } 
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have *lots* of controls (in this case - RadioButtons), then you can use the following trick - `Tag` property.

To summarize:

1) Set `Tag` property with the some string to differentiate from other controls (in particular, there may be the case when not all the controls of one type must be processed).

2) Collect these controls with defined string in `Tag` and process them.

In your particular case, you can set the string `ToCheck` in `Tag` and then check whether all RadioButtons are checked:

```
// Collect controls with defined string in Tag property
var radioButtons = this.Controls
    .OfType<RadioButton>() //Filter controls by type
    .Where(rb => ((string)rb.Tag) == "ToCheck"); //Get controls with defined string in Tag
// Check whether all RadioButtons are checked
bool allChecked = radioButtons.All(rb => rb.Checked);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool AreAllFalse(params bool[] thingsToCheck)
{
    return things.All(t => !t);
}
```

Usage

```
if (AreAllFalse(radioButton1.Checked,radiobutton2.Checked, etc)
{ 
   //Do what you want
}
```

The benefit of using the params key word is that it creates the array for you when you call the method. It also allows you to pass in just one thing to check if you want. While that would be quite pointless here, it just keeps things felxible and is something worthwhile knowing

Answer (score 0):

The possible approach could be to introduce variable for condition validation

```
bool optionIsSelected = ((radioButton1.Checked == true) || (radioButton2.Checked == true)...;
```

And then use it in if:

```
if (!optionIsSelected)
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("Please select an option!);
}
```